# FPC ACX2100 high CPU (99%)

Tags: juniper, cpu

I have an ACX2100 with high CPU usage in all FPCs.

```
juniper@ME-CSR-HNI_CGY-C100.1> show chassis fpc 
                     Temp  CPU Utilization (%)   Memory    Utilization (%)
Slot State            (C)  Total  Interrupt      DRAM (MB) Heap     Buffer
  0  Online            67     99          0       512        17         42
  1  Online            67     99          0       512        17         42
```

bcmDPC CPU assumption is not so high.

```
FFEB(ME-CSR-HNI_CGY-C100.1 vty)# show sched    
Total system uptime 1985+23:29:28, (171588473995 ms), 286829706944 thread dispatches
CPU load is 99% (1 second), 99% (5 second)
            99% (10 second), 99% (1 minute)
Total interrupt time 1442718795 (ms)

 CPU       Name      Time(ms)
 94%       Idle      161634193530
  4%    Threads      8511656149
  0%        ISR      1442718795
  0%    Level 1      1441461754
  0%    Level 2      1256495
  0%    Level 3      545

 Top Thread:
   pid      = 55
   name     = bcmDPC
   time     = 3235759084 ms
   cpu      = 1%

FFEB(ME-CSR-HNI_CGY-C100.1 vty)# show threads    
PID PR State     Name                   Stack Use  Time (Last/Max/Total) cpu
--- -- -------   ---------------------  ---------  ---------------------
  1 H  asleep    Maintenance            288/2056   0/0/0 ms  0%
  2 L  running   Idle                   264/2048   0/0/161634193595 ms 94%
  3 H  asleep    Timer Services         304/2048   0/0/14859788 ms  0%
  5 L  asleep    Ukern Syslog           304/4104   0/0/0 ms  0%
  6 L  asleep    Sheaf Background       384/2048   0/0/221141 ms  0%
  7 H  asleep    IPv4 PFE Control Background   240/8192   0/0/0 ms  0%
  8 M  asleep    DCC Background         264/4104   0/0/0 ms  0%
  9 M  asleep    DSX50ms                320/4104   0/0/26391897 ms  0%
 10 M  asleep    DSXonesec              696/4096   1/1/272362526 ms  0%
 11 M  asleep    GR253                  384/4096   0/0/911373 ms  0%
 12 M  asleep    mac_db                 240/8192   0/0/0 ms  0%
 13 M  asleep    RSMON syslog thread    896/4104   0/37/10673 ms  0%
 14 M  asleep    SFP                   1384/4104   0/497/417247211 ms  0%
 15 L  asleep    Firmware Upgrade       264/4104   0/0/0 ms  0%
 16 L  asleep    Syslog                1104/4096   0/0/35875 ms  0%
 17 M  asleep    Periodic              1288/8192   0/3/585715847 ms  0%
 18 M  asleep    PTP stack             2288/16392  0/0/241023182 ms  0%
 19 M  asleep    SyncApp               1232/16384  0/0/4591629 ms  0%
 20 H  asleep    TCP Timers            1064/8200   0/0/16065647 ms  0%
 21 H  ready     TCP Receive           1280/8200   0/0/24956568 ms  0%
 22 H  asleep    TNP Hello              472/2056   0/0/6543575 ms  0%
 23 M  asleep    UDP Input              320/2048   0/0/30888 ms  0%
 24 H  asleep    TTP Receive            816/4096   0/0/19576247 ms  0%
 25 H  asleep    TTP Transmit          1256/4096   0/1/49909989 ms  0%
 26 H  asleep    RDP Timers             200/2056   0/0/0 ms  0%
 27 H  asleep    RDP Input              264/2048   0/0/0 ms  0%
 28 M  asleep    RPM Msg thread        1024/4096   0/0/0 ms  0%
 29 M  asleep    RFC2544 periodic       448/8200   0/0/954437 ms  0%
 30 M  asleep    Pfesvcsor             1296/8192   0/0/26701747 ms  0%
 31 H  asleep    CLKSYNC PHY DRIVER     752/8192   0/0/614963 ms  0%
 32 M  asleep    CLKSYNC Manager       1224/16384  0/0/1 ms  0%
 33 M  asleep    PIC Periodic          2344/4104   0/10/1182639348 ms  0%
 34 M  asleep    PIC                    200/4096   0/0/0 ms  0%
 35 M  asleep    FFEB CM              13504/16392  0/614/168103736 ms  0%
 36 M  asleep    PPM Manager           4192/8192   0/0/261 ms  0%
 37 M  asleep    PPM Data thread       1928/8192   0/0/199841166 ms  0%
 38 M  asleep    VRRP Manager           296/8200   0/0/0 ms  0%
 39 M  asleep    L2ALM Manager         1264/8200   0/0/1293308 ms  0%
 40 L  asleep    Cattle-Prod Daemon    2104/16392  0/0/0 ms  0%
 41 L  asleep    ICMP6 Input            464/4096   0/0/0 ms  0%
 42 L  asleep    IP6 Option Input      1032/4104   0/0/0 ms  0%
 43 L  asleep    ICMP Input            1264/4104   0/0/638659 ms  0%
 44 L  asleep    IP Option Input       1016/4104   0/0/0 ms  0%
 45 M  asleep    IGMP Input            1016/4096   0/0/0 ms  0%
 46 L  asleep    DFW Alert              576/4096   0/0/786033 ms  0%
 47 L  asleep    NH Probe Service       264/4104   0/0/49 ms  0%
 48 L  asleep    IPC Test Daemon        672/2048   0/0/0 ms  0%
 49 M  asleep    PFE Manager           6256/16392  0/18/132403926 ms  0%
 50 L  asleep    PFEMAN Service Thread  1176/16392  0/0/0 ms  0%
 51 H  asleep    SNTP Daemon           1128/8200   0/0/87992 ms  0%
 53 L  asleep    Console               2296/16392  0/0/0 ms  0%
 54 M  asleep    PFE Statistics         720/8192   0/0/8465540 ms  0%
 55 M  ready     bcmDPC                1296/16384  0/0/3235762743 ms  1%
 56 M  asleep    bcmCNTR.0             1072/16392  0/7/1607639908 ms  0%
 57 M  asleep    bcmTX                  432/16392  0/0/30828032 ms  0%
 58 M  asleep    bcmXGS3AsyncTX         408/16392  0/0/0 ms  0%
 59 M  asleep    bcmLINK.0             2088/16384  0/1/640 ms  0%
 60 M  asleep    bcm563xx_icmp_rx      1248/8192   0/0/6414781 ms  0%
 61 M  asleep    bcm563xx_ttl1_rx       648/8192   0/0/4 ms  0%
 62 M  asleep    bcmRX                 1120/16392  0/3/205642028 ms  0%
 63 M  asleep    bcmL2MOD.0             528/16392  0/0/0 ms  0%
 64 M  asleep    Winpath stats          728/4104   0/0/8360240 ms  0%
 65 H  asleep    wp_isr_thread_fixme_name ISR   568/131072  0/0/0 ms  0%
 66 H  asleep    Winpath toolkit IMA event   632/8200   0/0/14025741 ms  0%
 67 L  running   Virtual Console       4560/16384  0/2/135 ms  0%
 68 L  asleep    Virtual Console        944/16384  0/0/0 ms  0%

FFEB(ME-CSR-HNI_CGY-C100.1 vty)#
```

But I see the below log continuously in the log messages:

```
%PFE-3: feb0 unit 0 L2X entry 23823 parity error
```

Please, give me some ideas to handle this case.
Thanks.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are KB about that log.
This may be a harmless log and can resolve by restarting feb.

https://supportportal.juniper.net/s/article/ACX-Different-parity-errors-are-seen-on-ACX-platforms

ACX1k, ACX2k and ACX4k platforms may be exposed to harmless parity errors that appear in messages.log.

There are two different types of parity errors:
Soft parity errors, which disappear after a FEB restart in the affected device.

Hard parity errors, which reappear even after a FEB restart. In this case, the errors are due to hardware problems and a replacement of the affected device is needed.
In most situations, unless obviously noticed, the parity errors are harmless for ACX1k, ACX2k and ACX4k platforms when printed in the form of messages.log. The only impact is the logs being printed frequently.